# JavaScript syntax highlighting with Reactjs went away in VSCode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

previously i don't remember configuring anything separately when working with React on VSCode, recently i had to clean install OS on my device but after that in VSCode my JavaScript Syntax highlighting broke here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcIF7.jpg), been trying to fix it since yesterday but to no avail, what can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax highlighting seems to work on the screenshots provided. On the bottom bar of VSCode you should have a button for Selecting Language mode
this should be AutoDetect or JSX in your case.

Comment: i already tried that but unfortunately it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes my all extensions stop working. I relaunch VSCode few times and it fixes my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I had to re-install VSCode in order to fix this issue

**IMPORTANT:** after uninstalling you need to navigate to C Drive and delete every data folder of VSCode left after uninstallation before re-installing it again.